# How to get hot reloading when using Buildpack for local Cloud Function development

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, buildpack

I know you can get hot reloading using `functions-framework` using `functions-framework --target=main --debug`, but I'd like to do my local development utilizing a container, so I figured I could build using `buildpack` and then mount the host function dir to `/workspace` in the container

Running `pack build --builder=gcr.io/buildpacks/builder unzip` yields a proper build (i think)

and running the following boots allows me to interact with the function properly via `curl`

```
docker run \
    -it \
    -v ${ADC}:/tmp/keys/FILE_NAME.json:ro \
    -ePORT=8080 -p8080:8080 \
    -e GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/tmp/keys/FILE_NAME.json \
    unzip
```

but when I try to mount the host dir like so:

```
docker run \
    -it \
    -v ${ADC}:/tmp/keys/FILE_NAME.json:ro \
    -v ~/empassion-ingest/functions/unzip:/workspace \
    -ePORT=8080 -p8080:8080 \
    -e GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/tmp/keys/FILE_NAME.json \
    unzip
```

I get the following error:

`IsADirectoryError: [Errno 21] Is a directory: '/workspace/main.py'`

Comment: Can you please try editing this line in your host dir `-ePORT=8080 -p8080:8080` into `-e PORT=8080 -p 8080:8080`  the space is important. Also you might want to check this [blog post](https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/python-isadirectory-errno-21-is-a-directory#:~:text=The%20Python%20%22IsADirectoryError%3A%20%5BErrno,and%20use%20a%20for%20loop.) regarding with the error you are having.